# Can I terminate my sewer vent pipe in the attic?

Tags: sewer, venting

Can a vent pipe stop in an attic crawl space as long as there is adequate ventilation in the attic?

Comment: Also, what's a "attic crawl space"? Usually, a crawl space is below the lowest finished living level of the structure, while the attic is above the highest finished living level. Low clearance in an attic is still just "attic".

Answer (score 1):

> Can it?

Sure! (But it probably won't meet code.)

> Should it?

Only if you like the smell of sewer gas in your house. The vent is not trapped, so there's no slug of water preventing whatever gasses and smells happen to be wandering around the sewer system from making their way up and into your attic.

You may *think* your attic is properly vented. This will tell you for sure.